# Typescript error with class attribute in MobX react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I'm unsure if this is an error with the way I am using MobX devtools, the way I am using MobX combined with typescript, or if it's an error in MobX Devtools itself.

My setup is react with MobX and TypeScript along with MobX DevTools - based on Create React App. The app is pretty much a copy paste of the 10 min todo introduction of MobX found [here](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started.html) The app works, but once I try to inspect the content of my store with DevTools I receive an error:

[image]

The code for the store is as follows:

```
export default class ObservableTodoStore {
    @observable 
    todos: any[] = [];
    @observable 
    pendingRequests: number = 0;

    constructor() {
        autorun(() => console.log(this.report));
    }

    @computed 
    get completedTodosCount() {
        return this.todos.filter(
            (todo: any) => todo.completed === true
        ).length;
    }

    @computed 
    get report() {
        if (this.todos.length === 0) {
            return '<none>';
        }
        return `Next todo: "${this.todos[0].task}". ` +
            `Progress: ${this.completedTodosCount}/${this.todos.length}`;
    }

    @action
    addTodo(task: any) {
        this.todos.push({
            task: task,
            completed: false,
            assignee: null
        });
    }
}
```

Any hints or things I should try out is most welcome.

Edit:
I should mention that the store is initialized in index.tsx and passed down to the components that interact with the store:

```
const store = new ObservableTodoStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <DevTools />
        <App store={store} />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

And finally:

```
export interface ITodoList { store: any; }

@observer
class TodoList extends Component<ITodoList, {}> {
    render() {
        const store = this.props.store;
        return (
            <div>
                {store.report}
                <ul>
                    {store.todos.map(
                        (todo: any, idx: string) => <TodoView todo={todo} key={idx} />
                    )}
                </ul>
                {store.pendingRequests > 0 ? <div>Loading...</div> : null}
                <Button onClick={this.onNewTodo}>New Todo</Button>
                <small> (double-click a todo to edit)</small>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onNewTodo = () => {
        this.props.store.addTodo(prompt('Enter a new todo:', 'coffee plz'));
    }
}
```

Maybe even more important: the error only pops up when expecting the store when using TypeScript. When not using TypeScript the inspecting works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should instantiate your store first after the store class:

```
export let myStore = new ObservableTodoStore()
```

Then wherever you want to access the store:

```
import {store} from '..pathOfStoreFile..'
store.todos.filter(item => item.completed === true).length
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've elaborated a bit on my question. I believe that I do follow your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't run your code, but I wouldn't pass the store as a prop, but instead write it like that:

```
export class ObservableTodoStore
{
    @observable
    todos: any[] = [];
    @observable
    pendingRequests: number = 0;

    constructor ()
    {
        autorun( () => console.log( this.report ) );
    }

    @computed
    get completedTodosCount ()
    {
        return this.todos.filter(
            ( todo: any ) => todo.completed === true
        ).length;
    }

    @computed
    get report ()
    {
        if ( this.todos.length === 0 )
        {
            return '<none>';
        }
        return `Next todo: "${ this.todos[ 0 ].task }". ` +
            `Progress: ${ this.completedTodosCount }/${ this.todos.length }`;
    }

    @action
    addTodo ( task: any )
    {
        this.todos.push( {
            task: task,
            completed: false,
            assignee: null
        } );
    }
}
export myStore = new ObservableTodoStore()
```

... and ...

```
import {myStore} from '..storeFile..'
@observer
class TodoList extends Component<{}, {}> {
    render ()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                { myStore.report }
                <ul>
                    { myStore.todos.map(
                        ( todo: any, idx: string ) => <TodoView todo={ todo } key={ idx } />
                    ) }
                </ul>
                { myStore.pendingRequests > 0 ? <div>Loading...</div> : null }
                <Button onClick={ this.onNewTodo }>New Todo</Button>
                <small> (double-click a todo to edit)</small>
            </div>
        );
    }

    onNewTodo = () =>
    {
        myStore.addTodo( prompt( 'Enter a new todo:', 'coffee plz' ) );
    }
}
```